# SSIS - move xml files to appropriate folder depends on Conditional Split result

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

I've got something like that:

[image: Control Flow]

and in Data flow the following code:

[image: Data flow]

I'm trying to parametrize the Output parameter in Output variable.
So, e.g.

- when Country in XML file is UK -> move XML file to folder C:\A
- when Country in XML file is not  UK -> move XML file to folder C:\B

Probably I need use Script Component?

This Output variable I would like to put in File System Task destination field,

Can someone help?

Comment: it is better to take [Stackover Flow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking your first question

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, you don't have to create `Case 2` in the conditional split, you can use the default output. (because if `Case 1` is false the row is redirected to the Conditional split default output)*

**You can do the whole procedure using one script component without the need of a conditional split**

Just do the following:

*Assuming that you are storing the Xml file Path in a variable named `User::XmlPath`*

1. Remove Conditional Split and both Script COmponents, also remove the file System Task
2. Add a Script component linked directly to the XML Source
3. Add `User::XmlPath` to the Script Component *ReadOnlyVariables*

[image]

4. In the Script Component write the following code

   ```
   Dim strPath As String = String.Empty
   Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
       MyBase.PreExecute()

       strPath = Variables.XmlPath
       '
   End Sub

   ' This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.
   '
   ' You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       Dim strFile As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(strPath)

       If Row.Country.ToUpper = "UK" Then

           IO.File.Move(strPath, "C:\A\" & strFile)

       Else

           IO.File.Move(strPath, "C:\B\" & strFile)

       End If

   End Sub
   ```